# How can I iterate between columns with v-slot in Vuetify data-table where I've dynamic columns

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, v-data-table

So, I have dynamiccaly changing columns in data-table. For example an S1, S2, S3-value column. And I'd like to put checkboxes in the cells, but not to the all, because I've name value. How can I made dynamically the `<template v-slot:item.S1="item">` and `<template v-slot:item.S2="item">`...

Thanks in advance for the reply!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution is the v-slot:item and v-data-iterator.